# Wordpress sql query not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I have term parent called 'product_parent' that has three childs terms :

- child_term_1 (id=2) (5 posts)
- child_term_2 (id=3) (3 posts)
- child_term_3 (id=4) (10 posts)

each post has **meta_key price ** (string) and i have to filter posts by price:

0 to 50, 50 to 100 and 100 +

this query works well (i can get 15 products):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM wp_posts as p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as p ON price.post_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_relationships as t ON t.object_id = p.ID 
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND t.term_taxonomy_id IN ('2', '3', '4') 
AND p.meta_key = 'price' 
AND p.meta_value LIKE '%50-100%' 
OR  p.meta_value LIKE '%100+%' 
GROUP BY p.ID
```

but if i add one filter :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM wp_posts as p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as p ON price.post_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_relationships as t ON t.object_id = p.ID 
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND t.term_taxonomy_id IN ('2', '3', '4') 
AND p.meta_key = 'price' 
AND p.meta_value LIKE '%0-50%'
OR p.meta_value LIKE '%50-100%' 
OR  p.meta_value LIKE '%100+%' 
GROUP BY p.ID
```

This returns "many posts" that not in term_taxonomy_id specified.

Someone could clarify me please? **i don't want to use Wp_Query(), i just want to use sql.**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you use the same alias

then duplicate alias

try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM wp_posts as p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN wp_relationships as r ON r.object_id = p.ID 
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND r.term_taxonomy_id IN ('2', '3', '4') 
AND pm.meta_key = 'price' 
AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%0-50%'
OR pm.meta_value LIKE '%50-100%' 
OR  pm.meta_value LIKE '%100+%' 
GROUP BY p.ID
```